# XPrivacy: ability to batch-set one permission for all apps?

Tags: permissions, xprivacy

I would like to select all (or multiple) apps in xprivacy, then revoke (for ALL of them, at the same time), the media/microphone permission (etc.)

(how) Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the ability to select multiple apps and then batch-applying a template is available in the Pro version of the app. That's not exactly what this question asks for, but it does seem that if applying just one permission change (instead of a whole template) exists or will ever exist, it will also be a Pro feature.

Source: https://forum.xda-developers.com/search/thread/2320783?query=batch